# ES6 combine two variables into an existing javaScript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm currently returning `createdAt` and `updatedAt` outside of the data object, I want to add them to the data object so I can return a single object.

I've also noticed I'm getting `$init: true` from somewhere, how to get rid of this?

```
  static profile = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
      const { username } = req.params;
      const account = await userModel
        .findOne({ 'shared.username': username })
        .exec();
      if (account) {
        const {email, loggedIn, location, warningMessage, ...data} = account.shared;
        const { updatedAt, createdAt } = account;
        res
          .status(200)
          .send({ data, updatedAt, createdAt }); // <=== How to combine updatedAt & createdAt into data?
      } else res.status(400).send({ message: 'Server Error' });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).send({ message: 'Server Error', error });
    }
  };
```

The current result is

```
createdAt: "2019-12-13T12:15:05.031Z"
data: {
 $init: true // <=== why is this here, where did it come from?
 avatarId: "338fcdd84627317fa66aa6738346232781fd3c4b.jpg"
 country: "AS"
 fullName: "Bill"
 gender: "male"
 language: "en"
 username: "bill"
}
updatedAt: "2019-12-14T16:07:34.923Z"
```

Comment: Instead of using a `...data` rest pattern, better be explicit about what properties exactly you want in the final object, like `send({ updatedAt: data.updatedAt, country: data.shared.country, … })`.

Comment: You mean `.send({data: {...data, updatedAt, createdAt }})` ?

Comment: About the `$init: true` I guess `account` is retrieved from mongo db. IIRC you are not supposed to use the result directly that way but you need to convert it to a plain object using `toObject`.

Comment: `const acc = account.toObject();
        const { email, loggedIn, location, ...data } = acc.shared;
        const { updatedAt, createdAt } = acc;
`

Comment: @Bill I would guess it should look like that. It has been a long time when I last used mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spread operator:

```js
{ ...data, updatedAt, createdAt }
```

Be warning, your variable name gonna be your index

Answer (score 1):

To remove `$init` but nothing else.

```
const {$init, ...cleanData} = data;
```

To create a data object with `createdAt` and `updatedAt`

```
const finalData = {...cleanData, createdAt, updatedAt}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: It is true that you can get rid of the `$init` in that way. But if it shouldn’t be there in the first place then the correct way in getting rid of it is to figure out where/why it was added and ensure that it is not added.

Comment: There were already comments addressing how to convert Mongoose documents into POJOs. I thought it would be better to add useful information for others dabbling with rest/spread. Over and out.

Answer (score 0):

Just use .toObject() like so:

```
static profile = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
try {
  const { username } = req.params;
  const _account = await userModel
    .findOne({ 'shared.username': username })
    .exec();
  const account = _account.toObject()
  if (account) {
    const {email, loggedIn, location, warningMessage, ...data} = account.shared;
    const { updatedAt, createdAt } = account;
    res
      .status(200)
      .send({ data: { ...data, ...{ updatedAt, createdAt }} });
  } else res.status(400).send({ message: 'Server Error' });
} catch (error) {
  res.status(400).send({ message: 'Server Error', error });
}
```

};